# File monitoring Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I created this script for check whether specific files exist or not in the given location. but when I run this its always showing

Failed - Flag_lms_device_info_20160628.txt do not exist
Failed - Flag_lms_weekly_usage_info_20160628 do not exist

but both files are existing.

```
 PREFIX="/opt/data"
 REPORT="/tmp/report.txt"
 DATE=$( date -d "${dtd} -1 days" +'%Y%m%d' )

    rm -f "$REPORT"

                FILENAME="Flag_lms_device_info_${DATE}.txt"
                FULLFN="$PREFIX/$FILENAME"
                if [ -f "$FULLFN" ]; then
                        echo "OK - $FILENAME exists" >> $REPORT
                else
                        echo "Failed - $FILENAME do not exist" >> $REPORT
                fi

                FILENAME="Flag_lms_weekly_usage_info_${DATE}.txt"
                FULLFN="$PREFIX/$FILENAME"
                if [ -f "$FULLFN" ]; then
                        echo "OK - $FILENAME exists" >> $REPORT
                else
                        echo "Failed - $FILENAME do not exist" >> $REPORT
                fi
```

Comment: As an aside, all-caps variable names are in a namespace defined by POSIX for use by variables with meaning to the shell or operating system -- user-provided variable names should have at least one lower-case character to avoid conflicts. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, 4th paragraph, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace (meaning that even if you don't explicitly command the shell to `export` it, setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable will overwrite the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have strange output in your question: your second line of output lacks a .txt extension. This might be an accident but if it's not it's worth investigating.

Assuming your date command is working correctly (I don't know that particular command), I would reduce your use of variables. In addition, I would use the -e test operator instead of -f because it's more inclusive. (If you haven't put data in the files yet, -f could return an error even if the file exists.)  :

```
REPORT="/tmp/report.txt"
DATE=$( date -d "${dtd} -1 days" +'%Y%m%d' )

echo "" > "$REPORT" # Wipes file instead of completely removing it

            filename="/opt/data/Flag_lms_device_info_$DATE.txt"                
            if [ -e "$filename" ]; then

                    echo "OK - Flag_lms_device_info_$DATE.txt exists" >> $REPORT
            else
                    echo "Failed - Flag_lms_device_info_$DATE.txt doesn't exist" >> $REPORT
            fi


            filename="/opt/data/Flag_lms_weekly_usage_info_$DATE.txt"
            if [ -e "$filename" ]; then

                    echo "OK - Flag_lms_weekly_usage_info_$DATE.txt exists" >> $REPORT
            else
                    echo "Failed - Flag_lms_weekly_usage_info_$DATE.txt doesn't exist" >> $REPORT
            fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -f "find "$FULLFN" -type f -name "$FILENAME"" ];then
```

Here you check for existance of a strange file named `find`... Use backquotes

```
if [ -f `find "$FULLFN" -type f -name "$FILENAME"` ];then
```

or, in `bash`,

```
if [ -f $(find "$FULLFN" -type f -name "$FILENAME") ];then
```

to get the command's output as a string.

Furthermore, your `find` invocation does not look promising. If you need to find a file named `Flag_lms_device and so forth` somewhere under `/opt/data/`, use `find "$PREFIX" -type f -name "$FILENAME"`. If you know for sure that `/opt/data` is the exact location, then use

```
if [ -f "$FULLFN" ]
```

and you don't need to `find` the file.

Comment: Did the OP edit the question to remove the code this answer refers to? BTW, `$(...)` is *not* a bashism; it's specified in the POSIX sh standard, published in 1992; thus, backticks are only needed with shells derivative of 1970s-era Bourne. AFAIK, the only vendor backwards enough to include a pre-POSIX shell in an operating system published in the last few decades is Sun -- and even they've finally cleaned up their act on that count.

Comment: Yes, the original question featured `find` commands in double quotes as conditions. Thank you for the note about backticks, probably last time I read this section of bash manual it was some vintage version, like that of ancient Solaris. >_<

Comment: *nod*, that sounds right -- Sun was perhaps your longest holdout, installing an original Bourne shell as `/bin/sh` and putting a POSIX sh instance down in `/usr/xpg4/bin` or somesuch. Fun, fun.

Comment: BTW, even in combination with backticks or `$()`, quotes are still necessary to avoid string-splitting if a filename has spaces; ie. `[ -f "$(find "$FULLFN" -type f -name "$FILENAME")" ]`. Bonus points to the behavior otherwise if a file is in a directory created with, say, `mkdir -- ' -a -z nonempty -a '` or something similarly mischievous in the context of `test` syntax.